# Azure Data Factory – dfproj cannot be opened because its project type is not supported by this version of the application

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am getting the below error when trying to create a solution
for Azure Data Factory:

> C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DataFactoryApp1.dfproj cannot be opened because its project type (.dfproj) is not supported by this version of the application.

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNiLw.png)

What should I do?

Comment: (1) Don’t post two different versions of the same message.  (2) Don’t post images of text unless they show information that isn’t present in the plain text.  (3) Describe what you are doing.  You say you are “trying to create a solution”, but the error message indicates that you are trying to open an existing file. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Microsoft Azure DataFactory Tools for Visual Studio 2015 by following below link -  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureDataFactory.MicrosoftAzureDataFactoryToolsforVisualStudio2015.

Close VS2015, open the dfproj project.